# JavaScript Server Call - Wait for Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am writing a server call to populate a map. I cant seem to get the code correct as to where it will wait until the Server Call is finished before moving on. I wrote the below function DoIt that calls someTimeConsumingthing that calls the server and populates the map. It will do the Server Call in SomeTimeConsumingThing however it will then Jump out of the function and go to the next code block.

```
export function onBeforePriceRules(quote, lineModels, conn) {
  var varQuoteHostid;

  if (lineModels.length) {
    var varProdIds = [];
    //Might want to do a function here.
    lineModels.forEach(function (line) {
      varQuoteHostid = quote.record["Host__c"];
      var varProdId = line.record["SBQQ__Product__c"];
      if (varProdId) {
        varProdIds.push(varProdId);
      }
    });
  }

  const UniqueProdList = [...new Set(varProdIds)];
  var ProdIdList = "('" + UniqueProdList.join("', '") + "')";

  let myMap;
  var ProductMap = new Map();

  //Call DoIt
  doit(conn, ProdIdList, ProductMap).then(function () {
    console.log("Now finally done!");
    debugger;
  });

  var NewVarable = "NewThing";
  console.log("NewVarable" + NewVarable);
  debugger;

  return Promise.resolve();
}

function someTimeConsumingThing(conn, ProdIdList, ProductMap) {
  console.log("someTimeConsumingThing");
  debugger;

  conn
    .query("SELECT Id, Model__c FROM Product2 WHERE ID IN" + ProdIdList)
    .then(async function (returnedRecords) {
      if (returnedRecords.totalSize) {
        returnedRecords.records.forEach(function (record) {
          ProductMap.set(record.Id, record);
          console.log("ProductMap" + ProductMap);
          debugger;
        });
      }
    });
   return ProductMap;
}
async function doit(conn, ProdIdList, ProductMap) {
  console.log("Calling someTimeConsumingThing");
  debugger;
  await someTimeConsumingThing(conn, ProdIdList, ProductMap);
  console.log("Ready with someTimeConsumingThing");
  debugger;
}
```

Comment: Indents?  It’s hard to read that code. Pls edit.

Comment: @zipzit refresh your page.

Comment: Don't create new promises when you already have one to use.

Comment: @trincot fair enough but it still doesnt work as expected.

Comment: There is much wrong with your code. You call `then`, but then continue with dependent code outside of that `then` callback. That will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a promise when you use

```
  conn
  .query("SELECT Id, Model__c FROM Product2 WHERE ID IN" + ProdIdList)
```

and you extend that promise by calling `then` which literally means do some thing after the promise has resolved. The problem is that you are not waiting for that promise anywhere, but instead you create a new one right after that, which you return and `await` in `doit` function.

```
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  });
```

What you want is to wait for the actual query promise, so edit your `someTimeConsumingThing` to return query promise, like so

```
function someTimeConsumingThing(conn, ProdIdList, ProductMap) {
  console.log("someTimeConsumingThing");
  debugger;
  
  // Imagine this as a block, that executes some time somewhere.
  // Everything outside of it gets executed when you call this function
  return conn
    .query("SELECT Id, Model__c FROM Product2 WHERE ID IN" + ProdIdList)
    .then(async function (returnedRecords) {
      if (returnedRecords.totalSize) {
        returnedRecords.records.forEach(function (record) {
          ProductMap.set(record.Id, record);
          console.log("ProductMap" + ProductMap);
          debugger;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Same with async/await syntax

```
async function someTimeConsumingThing(conn, ProdIdList, ProductMap) {
  console.log("someTimeConsumingThing");
  debugger;
  
  // Await for the query results
  const returnedRecords = await conn
    .query("SELECT Id, Model__c FROM Product2 WHERE ID IN" + ProdIdList)

  if (returnedRecords.totalSize) {
    returnedRecords.records.forEach(function (record) {
      ProductMap.set(record.Id, record);
      console.log("ProductMap" + ProductMap);
      debugger;
    });
  }
  return whateveryouwant
}
```

Read more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and dont be afraid to google how they work and/or explanation for them!

Comment: That makes sense. How would I make it wait for the promise in my SomeTimeConsumingThing?

Comment: @CodeMonger you should read more about https://javascript.info/async-await async and await. Basically promises and async/await are "same thing" (and still not) with different syntax, but one should try to use either one without combining a lot. Makes whole lot easier to follow code

Comment: Oh and you are already waiting for that promise in `doit` function, when you call `someTimeConsumingThing` with `await`

Comment: Correct. In your Answer, you said that I am not waiting for the promise. But I was waiting for the promise in the doit Function. I now understand that I am doing something after the promise in the someTimeConsumingThing using .Then but I am not sure how to wait until that something is done before moving on.

Comment: @CodeMonger if you want to do something for the promise in the `someTimeConsumingThing` you should do it inside the `then` function. Or you can change your syntax to async/await. I'll write an example in the answer for that

Comment: Ok that makes sense that I could then do everything in the Then Statement. Could you show how to do async/await possible for learning purposes.

Comment: @CodeMonger learning is always good, I added async await as example to my answer. If it satisfies your needs, dont forget to mark it accepted so others benefit from it too :)

Comment: So I tested out the answer for async function someTimeConsumingThing however it still for some reason doesnt wait for the Query Results any idea why?